# Two Latex installations on the same ubuntu system

Tags: pdftex, texlive, paths

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it comes with a basic TeX installation. I use LaTeX a lot and many of my packages don't come with ubuntu TeX installation. It's difficult and time consuming to download missing packages, go through all their files, read instructions, and put each file in the right directory. So I just installed texlive-full.

Although all packages are now installed (/usr/share/...), pdflatex (on terminal) does not find them. How can I find and set the right TexLive path for pdflatex?

I did run texhash.

In TUG, it says add this to your .bashrc:

```
   PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

But I don't have that path on my system. Where is the path to texlive binaries and how to export it? I don't even have "x86_64-linux" under any /texlive/ directory.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I think Ubuntu does some strange stuff with config files, anyway, take a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/24483 and see if it helps you.

Comment: It assumes that you know the path to texlive binaries. I do not have his path, instead, I have "usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/source/latex/koma-script/doc/bin", which just contains two .pl files. Doesn't seem to be the right path.

Comment: Did you intall through `Apt`?  If so, you should not be adding any `PATH` information.  If you added that line to your `.bashrc`, delete it and do `source .bashrc` (or restart computer) before trying to do any other 'fixes'.

Comment: I installed from command line: sudo apt-get install texlive-full

Comment: Ok, I removed the lines and restarted, problem solved! The PATH as you said, should not be set if you install through apt.

Comment: @eli You installed texlive-full and packages are missing? Which ones?

Comment: @eli Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

If you install the Debian package `texlive` through the package manager (`apt`, `aptitude`), then you should not set the path.

If you install separately by downloading `tlmgr` from the TeXLive website, then you do need to set the path (preferably in `~/.profile`, not `~/.bashrc`, but opinions differ).

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You should point out that `~/.bashrc` is shell-dependent. It will do you no good if you are using `zsh`, say. Also, if you install system-wide `/etc/profile.d/local_texlive.sh` and `/etc/profile.d/local_texlive.csh` or whatever are not bad choices.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you have the `texlive` package installed, but not `texlive-full`. If this is true, there are two options:

- install `texlive-full` with apt-get or your favorite package managers. It will bring you most packages there are, but a few released only recently.
- if you go for the installation of TeX Live from TUG, install to the default, and then adapt your `.bashrc` to add the parh.